# Map not reading code first time in Swift2 iOS9

Tags: swift, mapkit, swift2, ios9

I'm trying to display some shops in my map and it's working fine (the second time the user go to that MapViewController, but the first time (when it's asking for the user permission location) it only displays the user location and the map is not "zoomed" in the user location.

I'm going to show my code, it's very straightforward and simple:

**Updated with the new code (it's still not working and the "didChangeAuthorizationStatus" is not printing anything:**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let LoadURL = "http://www.website.es/shops.json"

var coordinates = CLLocation()

@IBOutlet weak var mapView:MKMapView!

var farmacia = [Farmacia]()

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var currentLocation = CLLocation()

var latitudeValor = String()

var longitudeValor = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self

    // Request for a user's authorization for location services
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        requestLocation()
    }
}

func requestLocation () {

    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse || status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways {
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        var currentLocation = CLLocation()

        print(locationManager.location)

        if locationManager.location != nil
        {
            currentLocation = locationManager.location!
            let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

            latitudeValor = String(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
            longitudeValor = String(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)

            self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

            requestPost()

            mapView.delegate = self
        }
    }
}

func locationManager(locationManager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    switch status {

        case .NotDetermined:
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            break
        case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            requestLocation()
            break
        case .AuthorizedAlways:
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            requestLocation()
            break
        case .Restricted:
            // restricted by e.g. parental controls. User can't enable Location Services
            break
        case .Denied:
            // user denied your app access to Location Services, but can grant access from Settings.app
            break
    }
}

/*
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    let location = locations.last as! CLLocation

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    requestPost()

    mapView.delegate = self
}
*/

func requestPost () {

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.website.es/shops_by_position.php");

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "latitude="+latitudeValor+"&longitude="+longitudeValor
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        // JSON RESULTADO ENTERO
        //let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        //print("responseString = \(responseString)")

        if error != nil
        {
            //print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        else
        {
            self.farmacia = self.parseJsonData(data!)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}

func parseJsonData(data: NSData) -> [Farmacia] {

    let farmacias = [Farmacia]()

    do {
        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

        // Parse JSON data
        let jsonProductos = jsonResult?["farmacias"] as! [AnyObject]

        //print(jsonProductos)

        for jsonProducto in jsonProductos {

            let farmacia = Farmacia()
            farmacia.id = jsonProducto["id"] as! String
            farmacia.nombre = jsonProducto["nombre"] as! String

            farmacia.latitude = jsonProducto["latitude"] as! String
            farmacia.longitude = jsonProducto["longitude"] as! String

            let stringLat = NSString(string: farmacia.latitude)
            let stringLon = NSString(string: farmacia.longitude)

            let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = stringLat.doubleValue
            let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = stringLon.doubleValue

            coordinates = CLLocation(latitude: latitude,longitude: longitude)

            let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

            geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(coordinates, completionHandler: { placemarks, error in

                if error != nil
                {
                    //print(error)
                    return
                }
                else
                {
                    if placemarks != nil && placemarks!.count > 0 {

                        let placemark = placemarks?[0]

                        // Add Annotation
                        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                        annotation.title = farmacia.nombre
                        annotation.coordinate = placemark!.location!.coordinate

                        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                    }

                }

            })
        }
    }
    catch let parseError {
        print(parseError)
    }

    return farmacias
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    let identifier = "MyPin"

    if annotation.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }

    let detailButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure)

    // Reuse the annotation if possible
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)

    if annotationView == nil
    {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
        annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "pin.png")
        annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = detailButton
    }
    else
    {
        annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return annotationView
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("PinDetail2", sender: annotationView)
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "PinDetail" {
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! FarmaciaDetailViewController
        destinationController.titulo_farmacia = (sender as! MKAnnotationView).annotation!.title!
    }
    if segue.identifier == "PinDetail2" {
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! FarmaciaWebDetailViewController
        destinationController.nombre_farmacia = (sender as! MKAnnotationView).annotation!.title!
    }
}

@IBAction func cancelToMap(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

**My question is:** What I have to change in order to show the user location zoomed and my shop entries the first time the app asks for permission and the user choose "Yes"?

It's my first time using the MapKit framework and I'm a little bit lost, so much appreciated if you can show me some light in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Change

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
```

to

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
```

2) Change

```
func locationManager(locationManager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

switch status {

    case .NotDetermined:
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

to

```
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

3) Add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to Info.plist

[image]

**EDIT**

4) Add the following code to `viewDidLoad`

```
locationManager.delegate = self
```

**EDIT 2**

5) Add `import` to header

```
import CoreLocation
```

Comment: Hi @KosukeOgawa, I have made all your changes and I have the same problem again. It displays an error: "Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first."

Comment: @Jordi  Add `locationManager.delegate = self` in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Check Settings > Privacy > Location Services > Your app. `While Using the App` is showing? http://photos2.appleinsidercdn.com/gallery/9485-1242-whileusingauth-l.png

Comment: Please update your post. I want to see the latest code.

Comment: Done, Thanks again for your help

Comment: I tried your code: http://i.stack.imgur.com/crLdD.png (the first time) this result is correct?

Comment: It seems to be, because at the moment my code only shows the user position and it didn't zoom in the user location the first time.

Comment: Ｍｍｍ Your code seem to be correct... I will comment, if I find out anything,

Comment: OK Thanks again @KosukeOgawa

Comment: I just have to add "Import CoreLocation" in my header and it worked. Please update your message with that step and I will accept your answer because it has been really good. Thanks @KosukeOgawa

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [requestWhenInUseAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestWhenInUseAuthorization) says

> When the current authorization status is kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined, this method runs **asynchronously** and prompts the user to grant permission to the app to use location services.

So in your code, the authorisation is requested and then execution immediately continues, eventually reaching

```
if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse
```

which fails, at status is still not determined.

There is the [locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:) callback in CLLocationManagerDelegate that is called once the user allows or denies location access.

I would suggest that you move your logic for the .AuthorizedWhenInUse case in a function and call it either from your viewDidLoad method for cases when authorisation is already granted or from the callback if it is not granted yet.

Comment: Hi @Mopt, I have updated the first message with more and new code. Why it's still not working? Thanks.

Comment: You have to set your class as delegate of the location manager.
You should create an instance of the location manager as an instance variable (if you create an instance only in viewDidLoad it will be destroyed once you exit viewDidLoad) and set it's delegate property to self. You must also declare your class as conforming to CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.

I can help you with that too, but if you need help with this, I strongly suggest that you read a bit on the delegate pattern in Cocoa.

Comment: Hi @Mopt, I have updated the first post with my full code for MapViewController. What is wrong in my code? Thanks again.